# "Cannot find assembly" error in VS 2008

Tags: c#, oracle, web-services, visual-studio-2008, odp.net

I had a web service on a 32-bit WIndows 2003 server that accessed Oracle database. It was built and converted to DLL with no issues. Then I had to port this to Windows 2012 64-bit server and I keep getting

> Could Not Load File Or Assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' Or One Of Its Dependencies.

I downloaded and installed 64 bit ODAC, but the problem remained. It was suggested to install the 32 bit version as well and I did that, so now I have two directories in C, `C:\Oracle\Products\11.2.0\client_1` and `client_2`, one for 64-bit and one for 32-bit. GAC also contains both x86 and AMD64 versions of `Oracle.DataAccess` and `Oracle.Web`. I still get the same error.

Looking closely, I found that when I close the error window in VS 2008, there is an output window that shows

> Warning: Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'oracle.dataaccess.dll'. Cannot find assembly  'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\oracle.dataaccess.dll'.

I checked and this folder is empty but there is a newer folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112.**3**.0__89b483f429c47342` with oracle.dataaccess.dll in it.

How can I resolve this issue? I don't know how to make the reference to `v4.0_4.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342` folder instead of `v4.0_4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342` folder, if this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: For testing copy Oracle.DataAccess.dll to your program folder where your EXE is located. Does it work then?

Comment: This is a web service so there is no exe. Also, it is not that the application canot find the DLL (DLL is in GAC), but it is either taking the wrong one or looking at the wrong place (look at the VS warning message in original post). I don't know how to force VS to look in the other folder for the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a copy of DataAccess.DLL in BIN folder. I removed it and all is well.